# Repeat column header for each group in ssrs reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

i am new to SSRS my requirement as follows

Data is as follows

```
Student Name    Score   Grade   Status

------------      -----    ------   --------
A              85   A   Passed
B              75   B   Passed
C              39   No  Failed
D              23   No  Failed
E              23   No  Failed
F              92   A+  Distinction
G              95   A+  Distinction
H              72   B   Passed
I              80   A   Passed
```

### Required output in report:

Failed

```
Student Name    Score   Grade
C   39  No
D   23  No
E   23  No
```

Passed

```
Student Name    Score   Grade
A             85    A
B             75    B
H             72    B
I             80    A
```

Distinction

```
Student Name    Score   Grade
F             92    A+
G             95    A+
```

Group by with status and for each group i need to show header with different colors like
for failed:'Red' and Passed:'Green' and for Distinction:'Blue'

Please some one help by providing step by step approach to achieve this

Please, please, please ....... its urgent

Answer (score 0):

Add a group to your table/grid (tablix) to group by Grade.  Then look at the properties for your group header.  Set the background color conditionally (using a formula).